# Auto-scaling integration runtime in ADF?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to horizontally or vertically scale a self-hosted integration runtime container in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Are your integration runtimes on-premise (which is a typical case)? If so, this is a local data center function - work with your data center team to scale up the VMs under your integration runtime instances, as well as to create new VMs to host additional runtimes.

Comment: Yes it is on-premise and the scaling should be automatic. Is there a solution in Python or in PowerShell to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Scale up - you can use `Update-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeNode` to set the concurrent job limit on a node, assuming the node being configured has enough resources to support the required job scale (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/update-azdatafactoryv2integrationruntimenode?view=azps-6.6.0)
- Scale out - you need to add nodes to your runtime pool, so

  - Allocating new VMs - that's a local data center issue
  - Registering new nodes on your integration runtime involves downloading an installer, and running it with appropriate parameters to set it up. Documentation for this is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-automation-scripts

Comment: Thank you! The document says you can only update "ConcurrentJobsLimit". Is there a way to update other parameters?